# Method GetById and SingleResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Here is my method that I use to get one entity in an ASP.NET Web API application.

```
[EnableQuery]
public virtual HttpResponseMessage GetById([FromODataUri]int id)
{
    // get concrete entity from repository
    var entity = repository.GetById(id);
   // check entity
    if (entity == null)
    {
        var message = string.Format("No {0} with ID = {1}", GenericTypeName, id);
        return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
    }

    // problem
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, SingleResult.Create(repository.Table.Where(t => t.ID == id)));
}
```

I'm using `SingleResult` for OData request (because `$expand` for single entity does not work if I do not create `SingleResult`). But in this case I repeatedly do almost the same action `repository.GetById(id);` and `repository.Table.Where(t => t.ID == id)`.

How can I improve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap the single entity into an IQueryable.  Something like this should work:

```
SingleResult.Create(new[]{entity}.AsQueryable());
```

You could write a helper function that uses this trick to convert from a single `T` to an `IQueryable<T>`.  There may even be a built-in way of doing this.

Comment: I wish [EnableQuery] + SingleResult knew how to return 404 OOTB

Comment: This is very much out of date, please no one do this anymore... this does not enable `$expand` it only serves to _trick_ the compiler and the OData runtime into executing, but you lose all the features.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller if you have a better solution, fee free to write an answer. I was only barely familiar with the technology at the time and haven't kept up with it since.

Comment: Ok, you talked me into it @PierreMenard My problem is that the internet is flooded with solutions like this that solve a very narrow scope of problems and end up blocking the rest of the OData pipeline, I personally feel that collectively all these quick fixes floating around the internet are the reason that OData v4 still doesn't have the market share that it deserves. That's not your or my fault, we don't know what we don't know. I just wish there were more best practices reference projects out there in the beginning, or even today, OData.org is so far out of date that it is a joke...

Answer (score 4):

`[EnableQuery]` and `SingleResult` does in fact return 404 OOTB, that is one of the key reasons for `SingleResult` to exist in the first place.

The problem is that your code is trying to return a raw `HttpResponseMessage` directly which will bypass the logic that makes this happen.

The basic implementation is simply this:

```
[EnableQuery]
public virtual SingleResult GetById([FromODataUri]int id)
{
    return SingleResult.Create(repository.Table.Where(t => t.ID == id)));
}
```

> **NOTE:** we have not used the `GetById(id)` method on the repo at all. The key is to use *IQueryable* responses from your repo or DbContext, then you can pass them straight through to the `SingleResult` factory.
>
> A core concept in OData is to avoid blocking the query and to delay execution right up until the `EnableQueryAttribute` can process it at the end of your method. `GetById()` looks like it resolves an item, so it has already executed the query against the DB without any of the additional projections that might be provided via `$select` and `$expand`. For `EnableQueryAttribute` to inject the necessary expressions we need to return an `IQueryable<T>` response that has not yet been enumerated.
>
> If you **do not** want to return `IQueryable<T>`, then you must manually apply the `ODataQueryOptions` or otherwise explicitly include all the possible navigation values that you want to support and eagerly load them... that's a lot of work that we get for free OOTB if we return `IQueryable<T>`

If you have a complex requirement that might involve returning different results in different scenarios, then you can use the `IHttpActionResult` instead of `SingleResult`. A common scenario is that you want to explicitly throw an exception when there are multiple results to your expression, the `SingleResult` implementation will simply return *TOP 1* from your query expression, and throw 404 when there are no results. *It will not throw an exception when there are multiple results, it will only return the first result.*

> Do not confuse `SingleResult` with the linq [`Enumerable.Single()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single) method that  throws an `InvalidOperationException` when the input sequence contains more than one element -or- the input sequence is empty

`SingleResult` doesn't implement `IHttpActionResult` so we can't return it easily from our methods OOTB, I use this method in my controller base that inherits from `ODataController`, you could re-write it as an extension method to `ApiController` if you haven't extended the default controller implementation with your own base class.

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper to Create a SingleResult (200 OK) Response as IHttpActionResult
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of item in query.</typeparam>
/// <param name="itemQuery">The query to get the item.</param>
/// <returns>A <see cref="System.Web.Http.SingleResult"/> from the specified <paramref name="itemQuery"/></returns>
protected IHttpActionResult SingleResultAction<T>(IQueryable<T> itemQuery)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, System.Web.Http.SingleResult.Create(itemQuery));
}
```

*This example of lookup by Id shouldn't ever really return multiple results, but it demonstrates how to do the check anyway*

```
[EnableQuery]
public virtual IHttpActionResult GetById([FromODataUri]int id)
{
    var itemQuery = repository.Table.Where(t => t.ID == id);
    if (itemQuery.Count() > 1)
        return InternalServerError();
    return SingleResultAction(itemQuery));
}
```

> I wouldn't advise moving the *greater than 1* check into the `SingleResultAction` method because that would force every query to evaluate twice, this is only provided as an example both of how to reuse the original `IQueryable<T>` expression and how to return `SingleResult` as an `IHttpActionResult`

Another common scenario where `SingleResult` is useful is with endpoints that *insert* data, so the `Post` method. If you use the `EnableQueryAttribute` on the Post method then instead of explicitly defining the possible expansions and returning a `CreatedODataResult` your can return `SingleResult` and get the added protection of validation that the item was actually committed to the database:

```
[OData.EnableQuery]
[HttpPost]
public virtual IHttpActionResult Post(TEntity item)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    repository.Table.Add(item);
    repository.SaveChanges();

    // item will now have been assigned an Id from the database
    var newId = item.Id;
    return SingleResultAction(repository.Table.Where(t => t.ID == newId)));
}
```

It's out of scope for here, but you could easily encapsulate all those `repository.Table.Where(t => t.ID == newId)` calls into an abstract method on a base class or change the `GetById()` to return `IQueryable<T>` not an instance of an item.

---

You really want to avoid the solution mentions in [this response](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/109187/81945) because it breaks the `IQueryable<T>` expectation that the query can be re-evaluated against the database. Using that solution will force you to also eagerly load all the navigation properties that you might want to support.